# Как получить координаты ближайшего объекта из множества других в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Нужно сделать так, чтобы каждый куб на сцене при движении рассчитывал расстояние до еды и если это расстояние меньше 10 единиц, то начинал двигаться к нему. Уже неделю пытаюсь реализовать эту затею, но сложность составляет то, что еда появляется на сцене каждые n секунд. причем произвольное перемещение работает нормально. Пробовал и присваивать в скрипте Food Script координаты объекта, и создавать отдельный GameObject, получая его координаты. Один раз получилось реализовать, но была ошибка с уничтожением объекта, т.к удалял префаб, а не сам объект. После исправления что-то изменил и теперь никак не могу вернуть... Я так понимаю, проблема в том, что мой скрипт перемещения куба не может выбрать определенные координаты, ведь еды на сцене много, но путает то, что как-то до этого работало. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
   public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject prefabCube;
    public Rigidbody cube;
    public Vector3 moveDirection;
    public Vector3 cubePosition;
    public float smoothing;
    private FoodScript food;
    private LevelManager levelManager;
    public int collectedFood;

    void Start()
    {

        food = FindObjectOfType<FoodScript>();

        moveDirection = transform.position;
       
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (food != null && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, food.transform.position) < 10.0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("This is foodDirection");
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, food.transform.position, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);

        } else
        {
        Movement();
        }
       
    }

    private void Movement()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(moveDirection, transform.position) < 0.5f)
        {
            //Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f)
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-40.0f, 40.0f), transform.position.y, Random.Range(-40.0f, 40.0f));
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveDirection, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
            
        }
}

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "FallDetector")
        {
            Destroy(prefabCube);
        }
       

    }
```

```
    public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timer;
    public float startTimer;
    public GameObject prefabFood;
    private PlayerControl player;
    private FoodScript food;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        food = FindObjectOfType<FoodScript>();
        timer = startTimer;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        
        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            timer = startTimer;
            SpawnFood();
       
        }
    }

    public void SpawnFood()
    {
        Debug.Log("This is SpawnFood");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(prefabFood, new Vector3(Random.Range(-40.0f, 40.0f), transform.position.y, Random.Range(-40.0f, 40.0f)), transform.rotation);
        }
    }




}
```

```
    public class FoodScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 position;
    private LevelManager levelManager;
    private PlayerControl player;
   


    private void Start()
    {
        position = transform.position;
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerControl>();
        levelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();


    }

    private void Update()
    {
        
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Научитесь работать с [событиями](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.14.php) (`event`) (обязательно)

Научитесь работать с [корутинами](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/Coroutines.html). Альтернатива `Update`, для не постоянных вещей. (желательно)

```
// запрет на несколько компоненов этого типа на одном GameObject
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class CubeManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // статическая переменная к которой можно будет обращаться глобально типа как Camera.main
    public static CubeManager Main;
    // список всех кубов
    public List<Cube> Collection;

    private void Awake () {
        Main = this; // Задаём данный обьект как Main
        Collection = new List<Cube>();
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class FoodManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static FoodManager Main;
    public List<Food> Collection;
    // событие спавна еда
    // Action<Food> - делегат некой void функции с аргуметом Food типа void Function (Food food)
    public event Action<Food> FoodSpawned;
    // событие удаления еды
    public event Action<Food> FoodRemoved;
    // префаб еды 
    // SerializeField - поле ведёт себя в инспекторе, как public, хотя и private,
    // в public нет смысла, другим глассам незачем иметь к этому полю доступ
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _foodTemplate;
    [SerializeField] private float _spawnStep;
    private float _spawnTimer;

    private void Awake () {
        Main = this;
        Collection = new List<Food>();
    }

    private void Update () {
        _spawnTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (_spawnTimer >= _spawnStep) {
            _spawnTimer -= _spawnStep;
            SpawnFood();
        }
    }

    private void SpawnFood () {
        GameObject NewFoodObject = Instantiate(_foodTemplate);
        Food NewFood = NewFoodObject.GetComponent<Food>();
        Collection.Add(NewFood);
        // передаём делегат с методом RemoveFood() для того, 
        // чтобы еда смогла удалить себя из листа и оповестить о событии удаления
        NewFood.SetRemove(RemoveFood);
        float PositionX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-100, 100);
        float PositionZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-100, 100);
        NewFood.Transform.position = new Vector3(PositionX, 0, PositionZ);
        // оповещает всех подписчиков о событии спавна с передачей ссылки на заспавниную еду
        if (FoodSpawned != null)
            FoodSpawned.Invoke(NewFood);
    }

    private void RemoveFood (Food food) {
        Collection.Remove(food);
        if (FoodRemoved!= null)
            FoodRemoved.Invoke(food);
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
// делает Rigidbody обязательным 
// автоматически добавит на GameObject, если его нет и не позволит удалить, пока есть Cube компонент
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private float _followDistance = 10;
    [SerializeField] private float _followSpeed = 1;
    private Rigidbody _body;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Food _followTarget;
    private IEnumerator _followCoroutine;

    private void Start () {
        _transform = transform; // кешируем, что-бы не запрашивать повторно (хотя в паследних версия "вроде" не надо)
        // берём компонент без проверки не боясь ошибки "null reference exception", поскольку есть RequireComponent
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        // добавляется в общий список кубов
        CubeManager.Main.Collection.Add(this);
        // подписывается на события появления и удаления еды
        FoodManager.Main.FoodSpawned += SpawnFood;
        FoodManager.Main.FoodRemoved += SpawnFood;
    }

    private void OnDestroy () {
        // при удалении куба, удаляет себя из списка и отписывается от событий
        CubeManager.Main.Collection.Remove(this);
        FoodManager.Main.FoodSpawned -= SpawnFood;
        FoodManager.Main.FoodRemoved -= SpawnFood;
    }

    private void SpawnFood (Food food) {
        Vector3 Vector = food.Transform.position-_transform.position;
        Vector = new Vector3(Vector.x, 0, Vector.z);
        // magnitude это длина Vector2/Vector3
        if (Vector.magnitude < _followDistance)
            StartFollow(food);
    }

    private void RemoveFood (Food food) {
        if (food == _followTarget)
            StopFollow();
    }

    private void CatchFood () {
        Destroy(_followTarget);
    }

    private void StartFollow (Food food) {
        _followTarget = food;
        // запускаем корутину движения, если она не запущена
        if (_followCoroutine == null) {
            _followCoroutine = FollowCoroutine();
            StartCoroutine(_followCoroutine);
        }
    }

    private void StopFollow () {
        _followTarget = null;
        // корутина остановилась бы и после _followTarget = null,
        // выйдя из цикла while, поскольку _followTarget в её условии, 
        // но вообще она останавливается так
        StopCoroutine(_followCoroutine);
        _followCoroutine = null;
    }

    private IEnumerator FollowCoroutine () {
        // безконечно выполняется, пока есть цель
        while (_followTarget != null) {
            Vector3 FollowVector = _followTarget.Transform.position-_transform.position;
            FollowVector = new Vector3(FollowVector.x, 0, FollowVector.z);
            // normalized выдаёт вектор, длинной 1
            Vector3 MoveVector = FollowVector.normalized*_followSpeed;
            _body.velocity = MoveVector;
            // ждёт до следубщего обновления физики как FixedUpdate
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
        // столкновение с едой
        if (other.GetComponent<Food>() != null)
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class Food : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform Transform;
    private Action<Food> _onDestroy;

    public void SetRemove (Action<Food> remove) {
        _onDestroy = remove;
    }

    private void Awake () {
        Transform = transform;
    }

    private void OnDestroy () {
        // при удалении вызывает ранее переданный метод удаляющий еду из списка и вызывающий событие
        if (_onDestroy != null)
            _onDestroy(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, решение попроще? Я только-только начал и мне бы хотелось понимать то, что у меня написано для того, чтобы улучшать и добавлять новые переменные, а не просто копировать чужой код. А то из написанного я так и не понял, почему это не работает... А насчет событий и подпрограмм я почитаю, спасибо)

Comment: Оно не сложное, кроме событий и корутин, ничего сверхестественного. Исправил ошибки, добавил комментарии. Разбираться в вашем коде не вижу смысла, лучше поразбирайтесь в моём, часок другой, вам будет полезно, поднимите скилуху и уже сами пересмотрите свои подходы. Задавайте вопросы тут по конкретным вещам или новые топики по общим.

Comment: П.С. не пользуйтесь `Find`! Это от лукавого. 1) Дорогая операция 2) Если нужно, значит у вас ошибка в проектировании.